# Validar confirmação de senha

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho dois *inputs* dentro do meu formulario: **Senha** e **Confirmar Senha**

Antes do usuário enviar o formulário, gostaria que fosse comparado o *valor* dos dois *inputs*. Se forem iguais, enviaria o formulário normalmente. Caso houver divergência entre eles, exibiria um "textinho" logo abaixo do *input* de **Confirmar Senha**.

Tentei fazer aqui, porém o formulário sempre é enviado, mesmo que as senhas estejam diferentes. Segue abaixo o que tenho feito:

```js
function validarSenha() {
  senha = document.getElementsByName('senha').value;
  senhaC = document.getElementsByName('senhaC').value;

  if (senha != senhaC) {
    senhaC.setCustomValidity("Senhas diferentes!");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input required="" type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
  <input required="" type="password" name="senhaC" id="senhaC" placeholder="Confirmar Senha">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="return validarSenha()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` nao retorna um array? voce nao deveria colocar `senha = document.getElementsByName('senha')[0].value;` ? porque acho que seu codigo do `if` ta verificando `undefined != undefined`, logo sempre sera `false`.

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, mas deu no mesmo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) retorna uma lista (mais precisamente uma [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)) que pode ter vários elementos. Então não funciona pegar o `value` desta lista diretamente.

Como os seus elementos possuem um `id`, e [os ID's devem ser únicos em uma página](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454716), basta usar [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) para obter os elementos.

Outro detalhe é que `setCustomValidity` deve ser chamado no elemento `input` e não no seu  `value` (da forma que você fez, ele seria chamado no `value` e não funcionaria). Então uma forma de resolver é:

```js
let senha = document.getElementById('senha');
let senhaC = document.getElementById('senhaC');

function validarSenha() {
  if (senha.value != senhaC.value) {
    senhaC.setCustomValidity("Senhas diferentes!");
    senhaC.reportValidity();
    return false;
  } else {
    senhaC.setCustomValidity("");
    return true;
  }
}

// verificar também quando o campo for modificado, para que a mensagem suma quando as senhas forem iguais
senhaC.addEventListener('input', validarSenha);
```

```html
<form>
  <input required type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
  <input required type="password" name="senhaC" id="senhaC" placeholder="Confirmar Senha">
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" onclick="return validarSenha()">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Outro detalhe é que temos que chamar também `reportValidity`, pois `setCustomValidity` [não mostra a mensagem quando é executada no evento de *submit*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538518).

Também retirei o jQuery que não estava sendo usado. Por fim, o atributo `required` não precisa ter um valor, então em vez de `required=""`, deixe apenas `required`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, resolveu meu problema aqui, abraço!

Comment: @DaviMonteiro Esqueci de comentar um detalhe, que `required=""` não é necessário ter o valor `""`, colocar apenas `required` é o suficiente (atualizei a resposta)

Comment: Eu sei disso, a primeira vez que eu aprendi foi com ```""```, é só costume mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Cara o que você pode fazer é verificar se as duas senhas coincidem quando o usuário terminar de digitar a confirmação da senha e clicar fora do input.

Lembrando que você deve fazer essa verificação no back-end também.

```
let inputPass = document.querySelector('#password');
let inputConfirmPass = document.querySelector('#confirmPass');

inputConfirmPass.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
   if( inputPass.value !== inputConfirmPass.value){
      alert('As senhas não coincidem');
   }
})
```

Comment: Funciona, mas eu queria fazer utilizando daquela forma que eu citei na pergunta...